# operand generation of CALL instruction on x86-64 AMD

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, machine-code

Following is the output of objdump of a sample program,

```
080483b4 <display>:
 80483b4:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483b5:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483b7:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 80483ba:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80483bd:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80483c1:       8d 45 fe                lea    0xfffffffe(%ebp),%eax
 80483c4:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80483c7:       e8 ec fe ff ff          call   80482b8 <strcpy@plt>
 80483cc:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 80483cf:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80483d3:       c7 04 24 f0 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484f0,(%esp)
 80483da:       e8 e9 fe ff ff          call   80482c8 <printf@plt>
 80483df:       c9                      leave
 80483e0:       c3                      ret

080483e1 <main>:
 80483e1:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 80483e5:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483e8:       ff 71 fc                pushl  0xfffffffc(%ecx)
 80483eb:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483ec:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483ee:       51                      push   %ecx
 80483ef:       83 ec 24                sub    $0x24,%esp
 80483f2:       c7 44 24 04 f3 84 04    movl   $0x80484f3,0x4(%esp)
 80483f9:       08
 80483fa:       c7 04 24 0a 00 00 00    movl   $0xa,(%esp)
 8048401:       e8 ae ff ff ff          call   80483b4 <display>
 8048406:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 804840b:       83 c4 24                add    $0x24,%esp
 804840e:       59                      pop    %ecx
 804840f:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048410:       8d 61 fc                lea    0xfffffffc(%ecx),%esp
```

What i need to understand, is in main we see the following at address - 8048401, call   80483b4 , however the machine code is - e8 ae ff ff ff. I see that CALL instruction is E8 but how is the address of function 80483b4 getting decoded to FFFFFFAE? I did a lot of search in google but it did not return anything. Can Anyone please explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

E8 is the operand for "Call Relative", meaning the destination address is computed by adding the operand to the address of the next instruction. The operand is 0xFFFFFFAE, which is negative 0x52.  0x808406 - 0x52 is 0x80483b4.

Most disassemblers helpfully calculate the actual target address rather than just give you the relative address in the operand.

Complete info for x86 ISA at: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-manual.html

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question. I've had a look at [Intel's documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and the `E8` opcode is `CALL rel16/32`. 0xffffffae is actually a 32-bit two's complement signed integer equal to -82 decimal; it is a relative address from the byte immediately after the opcode and its operands.

If you do the math you can see it checks out:

0x8048406 - 82 = 0x80483b4

This puts the instruction pointer at the beginning of the `display` function.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So this is only for NEAR calls. What about FAR calls? From your comment i understand that NEAR call is E8. Is FAR call E8 as well? Also, will the operand for FAR call will be abosolute addres??

Comment: @SamirBaid Far calls are `9a`and take absolute addresses. There is also `ff` which does something with absolute indirect addresses, but I'm not sure how those work. Check out page 716 of the combined volume set (i.e., the top one) on the page I linked for more detail.

Comment: @SamirBaid: Far calls are rare, even on x86_64. Library calls are usually done through a PLT, so you need a text segment bigger than 2 GiByte to make that happen.

Comment: Or put more simply, `rel32` calculated from the start of the *next* instruction, the first byte after the `call`.

Answer (score 3):

Near calls are typically IP-relative -- meaning, the "address" is actually an offset from the instruction pointer.  In such case, EIP points to the next instruction (so its value is `8048406`).  Add `ffffffae` (or `-00000052` in two's complement) to it, and you get `80483b4`.

Note that all this math is 32-bit.  You're not doing any 64-bit operations here (or your registers would have `R`s instead of `E`s in their names, and the addresses would be much longer).